# Inject a translated string as an input in an angular 5 component

Tags: angular, ng2-translate

I have an angular component template I want to inject `title` as an `@Input()` into, to be displayed as:

```
  <div class="title" >
    {{ title }}
  </div>
```

How do I inject the translated `title` into the parent component using ng2-translate's pipe, like so:

```
<title-component
    [title]="{{ 'KEY' | translate }}"
></title-component>
```

I want to pass the translated string dynamically to the child component, but I'd prefer to avoid injecting the translate service into the component's constructor and keep everything in the template, if possible. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried removing the `{{}}` from the input? They're usually not needed in inputs

Comment: That worked. Thank you. If you add your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`{{}}` are not required in inputs, so removing those should solve your issue