# pass translated value based on a parameter in angular

Tags: angular, string-interpolation, ngx-translate

I have the following translations

```
  "SIGNAL":{
    "0": "Initial state, unset state",
    "1": "Emergency",
    "2": "Dangerous state",
    "3": "Attention status, processing in progress",
    "4": "Attention",
    "5": "Normal status processing in progress",
    "6": "Normal status"
  },
```

each number is a error code from the server.

I have a component that display the error

```
export class DroneSignalLedComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() signal: number;
  @Input() status: string;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

I would like to pass the translation to this component in the status input.

Here is the binding

```
<app-drone-signal-led [signal]="uav?.signal || 0" [status]="{{ 'DRONE.STATUS.SIGNAL.'+uav?.signal | translate }}"></app-drone-signal-led>
```

The problem is, I can't find a porper way to concat my value inside the binding. (because there is also the {{}} of the translation)

right now I have

> compiler.js:2430 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: Parser Error:
>   Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 0 in
>   [{{ 'DRONE.STATUS.SIGNAL.'+uav?.signal | translate }}]

uav?.signal is a number that is from 0 to 6.

the result I would like, is that the optaining something like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49782701/inject-a-translated-string-as-an-input-in-an-angular-5-component)

`{{}}` are not required in inputs, so removing those should solve your issue

```
  <app-drone-signal-led 
    [signal]="uav?.signal || 0" 
    [status]="('DRONE.STATUS.SIGNAL.'+(uav?.signal || 0)) | translate">
  </app-drone-signal-led>
```

Comment: it compiles, but now I got another issue, the translate do not work, I just see ```DRONE.STATUS.SIGNAL.0```

Answer (score 1):

In continuation to Crocsx's Answer:

> {{}} are not required in inputs, so removing those should solve your
>   issue

As in your signal object the keys are only `0` `1` `2` & `3` so you cannot append `'DRONE.STATUS.SIGNAL.'` with these for translate to work, you only need to pass these digits to translate pipe separately like:

```
<app-drone-signal-led 
    [signal]="uav?.signal || 0" 
    [status]="'DRONE.STATUS.SIGNAL.'+((uav?.signal || 0) | translate) ">
</app-drone-signal-led>
```

Comment: yes, I wasn't showing the full path of the translation, so it was working with DRONE.STATUS.SIGNAL, thanks for the reply